# Spectral reflectance data for iron rust

Tags: data-request, research

Are there publicly available datasets of visible (and UV and IR, if possible) spectral reflectance data for the different types of iron rust?

Specifically, I am involved with a project that has an interest in the spectral/optical properties the different types of rust, particularly the 'red' and 'green' rust.

Preferably, a publicly available source of the data would be ideal, though if the data is included as part of a published paper, even behind a paywall - that would be okay as well (one of my contacts would be able to access that through his university library).  (If it turns out to be more than 1 resource, that is fine also).

While researching, it has become clear that through usual research channels, there is no obvious data sets for iron rust optical properties.  Much of the data available is about the electrochemical properties, and most of those are charts.

Comment: have you tried looking at nasa's remote sensing imagery?

Comment: I doubt that the data I seek would be from NASA remote sensing, the only rust related their remote sensing observations that I have seen are about 'yellow rust', which affects agriculture.

Comment: you doubt....so you dunno. aight, try this http://aviris.jpl.nasa.gov/

Comment: hmm interesting site, but it is not clear where rust spectral data would be available from it.

Comment: dude you gotta do the heavy lifting if no one has direct answer. nasa has this data

Comment: I will write to the contact person.  However, remote sensed natural iron rusted data is not exactly what I am after.

Comment: In the meantime, I would encourage any data from industrial-based research

Comment: the 2nd link isn't remote sensed. good luck

Comment: @albert what 2nd link?  I can only see the link to NASA's Avaris

Comment: yeah the second option. my bad

Comment: I have been exploring the NASA website, it does not quite have he data I am after - however, I have found an industrial-based data set that matches part of my request.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, I found a resource that has a myriad of spectral samples of just about all minerals (including rust) - [The RRUFF Project website](http://rruff.info/), where it contains

> an integrated database of Raman spectra, X-ray diffraction and chemistry data for minerals.

This site has a searchable database, the only (albeit minor) downside is that it does not allow for generic terms such as 'rust', but rather, the actual chemical names such as [goethite](http://rruff.info/goethite/source/asc/display=default/R120086) - a main component of 'red' rust.

Raw spectral data can be downloaded from the pages.

If there is difficulty in determining the real name, then [WebMineral.com](http://webmineral.com/help/Composition.shtml#.VSm_aPmUcVY) can assist, through a search facility that takes the chemical name and provides mineral names.